# How to install MySQL on 19.10?

Tags: apt, server, dpkg, mysql, 19.10

So I am following this [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/linux-installation-debian.html) to install MySQL, but I am getting error that predinstalled  `mariadb-client-core-10.3` is in conflict and that dependencies are not met, but I am unable to install them, since they are depending on MySQL. SO full log is here:

```
$sudo dpkg -i mysql-{common,community-client,client,community-server,server}_*.deb

(Reading database ... 290842 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-common_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) over (8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) ...
dpkg: regarding mysql-community-client_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb containing mysql-community-client:
 mysql-community-client conflicts with mariadb-client-core-10.3
  mariadb-client-core-10.3 (version 1:10.3.22-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-client_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing mysql-community-client
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack mysql-client_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server.
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server (8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack mysql-server_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) ...
Setting up mysql-common (8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client:
 mysql-client depends on mysql-community-client (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10); however:
  Package mysql-community-client is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-server:
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-client (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10); however:
  Package mysql-client is not configured yet.
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-community-server-core (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10); however:
  Package mysql-community-server-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-client_8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb
 mysql-client
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server




$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb-client-core-10.3

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 akonadi-backend-mysql : Depends: mariadb-client-core-10.3 but it is not going to be installed or
                                  virtual-mysql-client-core
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-community-client (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) but it is not installable
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-community-server-core (= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I run`sudo apt-get -f install`, it is asking me permission to remove, so:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client mysql-community-server mysql-server
```

What should I do?
Thank You on your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install mysql using apt, but first of all, stop mariadb process:

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
```

Then continue installing mysql via apt

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install mysql-server
```

and then you run this, and you follow the steps

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Then you should be able to log into mysql shell

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

EDIT:

You can delete mariadb completely too, and then run your command `sudo dpkg -i mysql-{common,community-client,client,community-server,server}_*.deb`.
Command for delete mariadb

```
apt remove --purge mariadb mariadb-*
```

ALERT: By running this, your databases may be deleted.

Comment: Hi, I am getting error that ```Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found```. so I have client for it installed, but It is not responding. And did you mean ```stop mariadb```?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i meant stop, but anyway, it returns that maraidb not found.

Comment: You should delete completely mariadb. Do you have any database in mariadb? Deleting mariadb, may remove all you existing databases.